# javascript error handling in script blocks

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

I have a lot of scripts on my page:

Example:

```
<script>
  window.addEvent('Updated', function(data) {

    /*I'm using a mootools javascript framework and my string below contain an error: 
      Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'empty' of null*/ 

    var container = document.getElement('cart_contents_data'); 
    container.empty();

  });
</script>
```

This error break all other code (script blocks).
I'm looking for the way to isolate script blocks (each other).

I'm tried something like this:

```
    <script>
          try {

             window.addEvent('Updated', function(data) {

               /*I'm using a mootools javascript framework and my string below contain an error: 
                 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'empty' of null*/ 

               var container = document.getElement('cart_contents_data'); 
               container.empty();    
             });

          } catch(err) {console.log(err)}

    </script>
```

But this solution doesn't help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
window.addEvent('Updated', function(data) {
    try {
        var container = document.getElement('cart_contents_data'); 
        container.empty();    
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Or even better, to avoid exceptions at all:

```
window.addEvent('Updated', function(data) {
    var container = document.getElement('cart_contents_data'); 
    if (container != null) {
        container.empty();    
    }
});
```

The problem is that the code `window.addEvent(....)` **only registers** an event handler. The actual event occurs latter, and is probably fired by the javascript framework. The exception occurs when the event is **fired**, not when being registered, which causes your try-catch block not to work at all.

Moving the `try-catch` block inside the function is a possible work-around, but in your case, it seems that the cause is trivial enough to avoid it with a simple `if` check. It gives better performance and improves code readability.

Comment: I know your code work. But I need solution to isolate modules code. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by modules. Do you use requirejs or any AMD module framework for Javascript? If so, add this to your question please (use the edit button)

Comment: No just <script></script> constructions.

Comment: @user889349. see my updated answer. Please, do not use the word modules, as this is incorrect terminology. Module is not a script enclosed with `<script>` tags, it is usually called _script block_. Modules refer to programmatic entities, usually build with the help of module framework (google curl, requirejs or javascript AMD modules). In your case, you have to fix your error one by one, there is no way to globally do a try-catch on everything, this is how javascript works.

Comment: This will allow you to call some code in case of error. Still the execution will stop as that code is done, and the rest of the script will not work. You must __individually__ address __each error__, until all get fixed

Comment: Understand... My programm allow code editing on the page in a textarea. If someone do mistake with the code and press save -> page refresh -> they lost an access to the code editing to fix this error :( This is a big problem.

Comment: You should separate the code being edited from the code you use in your application - like loading the edited page in an iframe or etc, with the editor outside the iframe. There might be better solutions, but it seems your current state will not work. Do some research and try again. This post will become too long if we continue discussion, and I fear the topic is exhausted (regarding the question). I recommend asking a new one with this information for the CMS functionality, or rewriting this qeustion